# Intercepting outgoing Kendo Grid calls to add JWT authrization header

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, kendo-ui, single-page-application, jwt

I am working on a Single page application using AngularJs. My application uses JWT Authorization header token for authorization.  I have agularJs interceptor that adds the Authorization header to every outgoing api call from my SPA application.

I recently added Kendo UI to the application and i noticed that the api calls made by Kendo Grid are not passing through my Angular interceptor.

Is there a clean way to intercept all out going API calls from KendoUi components so that i can add Authorization header token ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  function setAuthHeader(req) {

        var token = tokenStoreService.getToken();
        if (token) {
            req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
        }
    }

    function setGridAuthorization(dataSource) {
        if (dataSource && dataSource.transport && dataSource.transport.options) {
            var opt = dataSource.transport.options;
            if (opt.read) opt.read.beforeSend = setAuthHeader;
            if (opt.update) opt.update.beforeSend = setAuthHeader;
            if (opt.destroy) opt.destroy.beforeSend = setAuthHeader;
            if (opt.create) opt.create.beforeSend = setAuthHeader;

        } else if (dataSource && dataSource.transport) {
            var tran = dataSource.transport;
            if (tran.read) tran.read.beforeSend = setAuthHeader;
            if (tran.update) tran.update.beforeSend = setAuthHeader;
            if (tran.destroy) tran.destroy.beforeSend = setAuthHeader;
            if (tran.create) tran.create.beforeSend = setAuthHeader;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what about server side excel export ?Is there a clean way to intercept all out going "Proxy Excel Export" calls from KendoUi components so that i can add Authorization header token? thanks in advance